# Dictionary phonebook with userInput, but with a twist

Tags: python

I have been working on this for too long. It should be simple and I've ran through many different combinations, however, I keep getting the code wrong and have no idea why. It works fine when I have manual input, but when I submit there is an error.

question prompt:
Write a program that keeps a dictionary of names and their corresponding phone numbers.

Repeatedly ask the user for a name. Then, do one of the following three things, depending on what they enter:

If they enter nothing, exit the program.
If they enter a name that exists as a key in your dictionary, simply print the corresponding phone number.
If they enter a name that is NOT in your dictionary as a key, ask the user for a phone number, and then put the name and phone number in your dictionary.
Print out the final dictionary.

my code:

```
phoneBook = {}
name = input("Please enter a name(or press enter to end input): ")
while name != '':
    if not name in phoneBook:
        number = input("Please enter number: ")
    print "Phone number: " + number
    phoneBook[name] = number
    name = input("Please enter a name(or press enter to end input): ")
    if name in phoneBook:
        print phoneBook[name]
    if name == '':
        break
print phoneBook
```

Expected result:

```
    Phone number: 1234
    Phone number: 5678
    {'Tracy': '5678', 'Karel': '1234', 'Steve': '9999'}
```

My result:

```
Phone number: 1234
Phone number: 5678
Phone number: 9999
1234
Phone number: 9999
5678
Phone number: 9999
{'Tracy': '9999', 'Karel': '9999', 'Steve': '9999'}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
phoneBook = {}
name = input("Please enter a name(or press enter to end input): ")
while name != '':
    if not name in phoneBook.keys():
        number = input("Please enter number: ")
        phoneBook[name] = number
        print "Phone number: " + number
        name = input("Please enter a name(or press enter to end input): ")
    else:
        print phoneBook[name]

print phoneBook
```

Try the above code.
When a name is not in the phoneBook, then assign the name a number, so `phoneBook[name] = number` should be in the `if not name in phoneBook.keys():` block. And then enter another name in the same if block.

Answer (score 0):

you must also access the dictionary keys for checking the existence of a name:

```
if not name in phoneBook.keys():
```